# Play! framework. create a new view

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.0, web-development-server

I created a new project using the play console
now, by default I got in my views directory two files:

```
main.scala.html   
index.scala.html
```

I want to add a new view file. I call it "forums.scala.html"
now, I know that in order to render a view you need to do this:

```
views.html.forums.render("Forums");
```

the problem is that the intellisense doesn't recognize "forums"
but index and main it does recognize.
I've noticed those files:

> class_managed/views.html/index.class
>   class_managed/views.html/main.class

but there is no forums.class so I suspect this is the problem.
I tried to build the project, but it didn't help.
so, what is the solution?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your new views are compiled to managed sources after next browser hit if you are using `play run` for starting Play in dev mode.

If you'll use `play ~run` it will try to compile it as soon at it will recognize change in the file.

Finally if you started your app in production mode ie. via `play start` you have to stop it with `ctrl+c` and run again. Anyway, developing application in production mode is just a bad idea :)

Depending on your IDE most probably you'll need to refresh file structure to allow it find freshly created managed sources.

Comment: no. it didn't help. I ran the application with this command: "play ~run", but still the forums.scala.html didn't compiled to the managed sources.

Answer (score 6):

right click on ther project and click refresh, that worked for me - found it in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.
running "compile" command did the work.
I understood that intelliJ do it auto, so I will probably use it instead of eclipse.

cheers!

Comment: But you clicked 'compile' in the IDE ? Normally Play's console compiles files beside the used software (if running) so the application should work properly even if IDE shows it as unresolved parts (until next manual refreshing). And yes IntelliJ watches the resources and recognizes them ASAP

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program in scala, my recommendation is to forget about intellisense. Eclipses scala-ide is quite buggy, dont know about netbeans. And because of nonstandard layout of play2 application, non std development tools (play console), it becames even more handy to use simple text redactor (like sublime or textmate) with good old open-folder-as-project feature.

Comment: You should try IntelliJ Idea. In current version (11) it starts to recognize freshly compiled view-classes just a few seconds after compilation (there is small lag, however it doesn't required to perform any action from the user). New version that will be available at te end of this year (12 - Leda) probably will work even better, as there is planned special support for Play 2.x